# What's the meaning about this conclution of annihilating polynomials in Kunze and Hoffman's book?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

'T is a linear operator on the n-dimensional space V. The first $n^2+1$ powers of T:

$I,T,T^2,…,T^{n^2}.$

This is a sequence of $n^2+1$ operators in *L(V,V)* ,the space of linear operators on V which has dimension $n^2$.Therefore,that sequence of $n^2+1$ operators must be linearly dependent,i.e.,we have

$c_0I+c_1T+…+c_{n^2}T^{n^2}=0$

for some scalars $c_i$ ,not all zero.

So,the ideal of polynomials which annihilate T contains a non-zero polynomials of degree $n^2$ or less.'

I can't understand the conclusion of this remark "the ideal of polynomials which annihilate T contains a non-zero polynomials of degree $n^2$ or less".

I can understand the dependence of $n^2+1$ operators.But how we get the conclusion about the ideal of polynomials?In what ways?

Comment: Do you know what an ideal is?  Do you know what it means for a polynomial to annihilate $T$?

Comment: of course.I have learnt.

Comment: the linear dependence relation is also a polynomial which annihilates $T$. just look at it. what is its degree?

Comment: I know that's mean that  for every ideal in the polynomial algebra F[x] over F, polynomials in the ideal have degree $n^2$ or more must be linear dependent.

Comment: All it means is that the polynomial $c_0+c_1x+\dotsb+c_{n^2}x^{n^2}$ annihilates $T$.

Comment: If $c_0I+c_1T+\cdots+c_{n^2}T^{n^2}=0$, then $c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_{n^2}x^{n^2}$ belongs to the ideal of polynomials which annihilate $T$. Hence, the ideal of polynomials which annihilate $T$ contains a non-zero polynomial with degree at most $n^2$.

Comment: Thanks.I get it.But polynomials which annihilate T form a ideal of F[x] over F.What's the ideal of polynomials which annihilate T? Is that mean the same thing?English is not my native language.

Comment: The ideal is the set of polynomials which annihilate $T$.  It is an ideal because if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials that annihilate $T$ and $a$ and $b$ are in the field $\mathbb F$, $af + bg$ is a polynomial that annihilates $T$, and if $h$ is any polynomial, $f h$ is a polynomial that annihilates $T$.